# Как отправить фото в телеграм боте

Tags: python, telegram

Возникла трудность с отправкой фото в телеграм боте. Вот мой код:

```
anime_image = Image.open(DIR)
new_width = 512
new_height = 512
anime_image.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=Image.open(BytesIO(anime_image)), caption='Готово!')
```

Выдает ошибку: "a bytes-like object is required, not 'PngImageFile'"
Так же пробовал

```
bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=BytesIO(anime_image), caption='Готово!')
```

Так же не работает!

Comment: Не знаю в чем причина, но через Image.open и у меня ничего не вышло. PIL виноват? Использовал 'import os'  и для открытия файла: 'open("имя файла","rb")'. В этой связке все получилось с отправкой фото в чат телеграм-бота.

Answer (score 1):

```
# отправка двух фото как альбом
with open('./files/menu/bar.jpg', 'rb') as f1, open('./files/menu/kitchen.jpg', 'rb') as f2:
        bot.send_media_group(call.message.chat.id, [InputMediaPhoto(f1), InputMediaPhoto(f2)])
```